# Magento 2 : Replace labels in invoice pdf

Tags: magento, magento2

I am new in magento 2. I am facing problem in replacing labels in pdf invoice. I need to replace "Tax" label by "GST" label which is present at right hand bottom. I have wasted more than 6 hours on this but not getting any solution.

Please help me in this.

Comment: The solution you got @mahesh seems ok, but for enhanced GST functionality, you can also take a look at GST extension available for Magento 2 here https://magecomp.com/magento-2-indian-gst.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution. I have replaced "Tax" label to "GST" in `vendor/magento/module-tax/i18n/en_US.csv` file. This change got reflected throughout the website.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you will need to create tax rules and they will be displayed under tax as summary. You can also change the TAX label in your checkout but you can not easily customise the invoice. Also, you will also need to show CGST and SGST individually.

For that try creating tax rules.

**Step 1:** Fill the Tax Rule Information

- On the Admin Panel, Stores > Taxes > Tax Rules.
- In the upper-right corner, click on Add New Tax Rule.
- Under the Tax Rule Information section, set Name for the new rule.
- From the tax rate list, choose one of them to enable for the rule. However, for each the existing tax rate, you can edit it as the following:

  - Tap the Edit icon on the row.
  - Edit the tax rate information on the Tax Rate page, then click Save.
- Click on Add New Tax Rate.
- Complete the Tax Rate form.
- Save to complete.

**Step 2:** Configure the Additional Settings

- On the Tax Rule page, open Additional Settings section,

  - Choose the Customer Tax Class area to which the rule applies.

    - Tap the Edit icon to modify the form and then Save it.
    - If need to create a new tax class, click on Add New Tax Class to fill the necessary information and then Save it.
  - Choose the Product Tax Class to which the rule applies.

    - Tap the Edit icon to modify the form and then Save it.
    - If need to create a new tax class, click on Add New Tax Class to fill the necessary.
  - Set the Priority to determine this tax to be applied first when more than one tax are enabled
  - To calculate the tax according to the order subtotal, mark the Calculate off Subtotal Only checkbox.
  - Set the Sort Order to arrange them in the list of the tax rules.

I hope this helps. For more refer [Magento User Guide](http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/magento/magento-community-edition-2.1-user-guide.html)

Comment: I will try with above steps. Could you please tell me how to replace TAX label with GST label in theme. I have tried lot but not getting results.

Comment: To change TAX to GST in the invoice you will need to instal a third part plugin for invoicing that allows editing the text on invoice. Magento does not allow to edit the content of the invoice. 
To change TAX to GST in checkout, you will need to edit your template which will differ from template to template. Kindly go through the documentation of your template to see how you can do that.